# Multiple select not working while submiting please give me to select multiple option code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```html
<form method='post' action=''>
  <select name='select1' multiple="true">
    <option value='1' <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'select1'])) { if($_POST[ 'select1']=='1' ) { echo 'selected'; } } ?>>imtiyaz</option>
    <option value='2' <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'select1'])) { if($_POST[ 'select1']=='2' ) { echo 'selected'; } } ?>>narendra</option>
    <option value='3' <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'select1'])) { if($_POST[ 'select1']=='3' ) { echo 'selected'; } }?>>shekar</option>
  </select><br><br><br>

  <select name='select2' multiple>
    <option value='1' <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'select2'])) { if($_POST[ 'select2']=='1' ) { echo 'selected'; } } ?>>sumit</option>
    <option value='2' <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'select2'])) { if($_POST[ 'select2']=='2' ) { echo 'selected'; } } ?>>arun</option>
    <option value='3' <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'select2'])) { if($_POST[ 'select2']=='3' ) { echo 'selected'; } } ?>>vinay</option>
  </select><br><br><br>

  <select name='select3' multiple>
    <option value='1' <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'select3'])) { if($_POST[ 'select3']=='1' ) { echo 'selected'; } } ?>>rohth</option>
    <option value='2' <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'select3'])) { if($_POST[ 'select3']=='2' ) { echo 'selected'; } } ?>>pawan</option>
    <option value='3' <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'select3'])) { if($_POST[ 'select3']=='3' ) { echo 'selected'; } } ?>>suresh</option>
  </select>

  <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

My mutiple select box is not working while submiting the form and also i want to display values in select box after refresh the page which i have selected

Comment: What do you mean 'it's not working'? That not nearly enough information for anyone to help you

Comment: You should probably start with changing your elements into arrays: `name='select1[]'`, etc.

Comment: when i am submiting the form i can get multiple values in select

Comment: yeh its not working

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior and **a specific problem or error*** - "not working" is not a specific problem or error.  Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select name='select1[]' multiple= "true">
```

The name of the multi select drop down must be an array so that it can accept multiple selected value in it. You can use it by iterating the array using foreach() like:

```
foreach($_REQUEST['select1'] as $selection)
{
    // your code
}
```